# CosmosDB MongoDB-API omitting enums if value equals zero

Tags: c#, enums, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Currently, We are moving a project from MongoDB to CosmosDB with the MongoDB API. In the datamodel we sometimes use enums and store them (represented as int, using the default serializer) in the DB as well.

After experiencing issues in rare cases, we observed, that enums are not stored in the CosmosDB, when their value is equal to 0. (MongoDB stores them in this case)

Is there a way to force the CosmosDB to store these entries? Restructuring the program would be major work and should be avoided.

Example:

```
public enum EPower
{
    mW = 0,
    W = 1,
    kW = 2
}
```

Inserting via

```
var obj = new ContainingType();
// client is MongoClient
var db = client.GetDatabase(MyDB);
var collection = db.GetCollection<ContainingType>(MyCollection);
await collection.InsertOneAsync(obj);
```

Will be stored in MongoDB:

```
{
  "SomeProp": "foo",
  "Power": 0
}
```

and in CosmosDB:

```
{
  "SomeProp": "foo"
}
```

We also tried forcing a different representation of the enum via ConventionPacks

```
ConventionRegistry.Register("EnumStrings",
                        new ConventionPack { new EnumRepresentationConvention(BsonType.String)  },
                        t => true);
```

But still the enums are omitted if their value is 0. (Besides this kind of storage is bad)

Comment: I guess, using 0 for "None" - Entry, leaving all "serious" Entries with a value > 0 is no option?

Comment: Not really, else the problem would be solved

Answer (score -2):

No reason to store as an `Enum`. Just use a class instead:

```
public class EPower
{
    public int mW = 0;
    public int W = 1;
    public int kW = 2;
}
```

Comment: As stated, this is an existing application relying on enums and making the definition available outside

Comment: Fine so create a mapping class between the enum and the dto?